# Variance of sum of multiplication of independent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that we have $Z=\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i+b_iX_i)(c_i+d_iY_i)$. Where $a_i,b_i,c_i$ and $d_i$ are real numbers and $X_i$s and $Y_i$s are all independent random variables. How can I find the variance of the random variable *Z*?

Comment: Use $E(Z^2)-E^2(Z)$. If the variables are all independent, then $E \Pi_i(a_i+b_i X_i)=\Pi_i (a_i + b_i E(X_i))$..

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find $E(Z^2)$?

Comment: Use $Z^2=\sum_{i,j}(a_i+b_i X_i)(c_i+d_iY_j)(a_j+b_j X_j)(c_j+d_j Y_j)$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathbb{E}}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{\mathbb{Var}}}$If the random variables are mutually independent:
$$\begin{align}A\bot B &\iff \E(A B)=\E(A)\E(B) 
\\ A \bot B &\iff (n+A) \bot (m+B) 
\\ A \bot B &\iff nA\bot mB 
\\ A \bot C, B\bot C &\implies AB \bot C
\end{align}$$

So:
$\begin{align}
  \text{Let } P_i & = a_i+b_iX_i 
\\ \E(P_i) & = a_i+b_i\E(X_i)
\\ \E(P_i^2) & = a_i^2+2a_ib_i\E(X_i)+b_i^2\E(X_i^2)
\\ \Var(P_i) & = \E(P_i^2)-\E(P_i)^2
\\ & = a_i^2+2a_ib_i\E(X_i)+b_i^2\E(X_i^2) - a_i^2 - 2 a_ib_i\E(X_i)- b_i^2\E(X_i)^2
\\ & = b_i^2\Var(X_i)
\\[2ex]\text{by symmetry} 
\\ \text{Let } Q_i & = c_i+d_iY_i 
\\ \E(Q_i) & = c_i+d_i\E(Y_i) 
\\ \Var(Q_i) & =d_i^2\Var(Y_i)
\\[2ex]\text{Let } R_i & = P_iQ_i
\\ \E(R_i) & = \E(P_i)\E(Q_i) & \ni P_i \bot Q_i
\\ \E(R_i^2) & = \E(P_i^2)\E(Q_i^2)
\\ \Var(R_i) & = \E(P_i^2)\E(Q_i^2)-\E(P_i)^2\E(Q_i)^2
\\ &= \Var(P_i)\Var(Q_i) + \Var(P_i)\E(Q_i)^2 + \Var(Q_i)\E(P_i)^2
\\ & = b_i^2d_i^2\Var(X_i)\Var(Y_i) \\ & \quad + b_i^2\Var(X_i)(c_i+d_i\E(Y_i))^2 \\ & \quad + d_i^2\Var(Y_i)(a_i+b_i\E(X_i))^2
\\[2ex] \text{Let } Z & = \sum_i R_i
\\ \Var(Z) & = \sum_i \Var(R_i) & \ni R_i\bot R_j, \forall i\neq j
\\ & = \sum_i b_i^2d_i^2\Var(X_i)\Var(Y_i) \\ & \quad + \sum_i b_i^2\Var(X_i)(c_i+d_i\E(Y_i))^2 \\ & \quad + \sum_i d_i^2\Var(Y_i)(a_i+b_i\E(X_i))^2
\end{align}$